# How to disable Ctrl-u on a Joomla 3 website

Tags: joomla, keyboard-shortcuts

My client wants to disable the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in his Joomla 3 website. I have noticed on many various websites when I'm trying to view the code by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> it pops up a blank page with nothing on it. Is this possible to be done on a Joomla 3 website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The code will be always shown. Actually this code is what is used by your browser to display the website...